# Problem Using Roscore and Roslaunch in Groovy

Tags: roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am relatively new to ROS. Recently I installed Groovy on my Linux machine and some new packages only to be given the error:

WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Cannot locate [roslaunch]Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1].

Param xml is param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/
Furthermore, I get the same error message when trying to use roscore.

I have seen this error in other threads; however, I have already followed the instructions given and gotten no results.

Is there a way to direct rosversion to the location of roslaunch to get rid of this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54686/problem-using-roscore-and-roslaunch-in-groovy/) by [Jacob Guerra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4157/jacob-guerra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've seen this error when roslaunch is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  Make sure that it is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  For more information see  [the wiki page for envionrment variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) and [filesystem tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0